# breakpoint in except clause doesn't have access to the bound exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, breakpoints, pdb

Consider the following example:

```py
try:
    raise ValueError('test')
except ValueError as err:
    breakpoint()  # at this point in the debugger, name 'err' is not defined
```

Here, after the [breakpoint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#breakpoint) is entered, the debugger doesn't have access to the exception instance bound to `err`:

```
$ python test.py 
--Return--
> test.py(4)<module>()->None
-> breakpoint()
(Pdb) p err
*** NameError: name 'err' is not defined
```

Why is this the case? How can I access the exception instance? Currently I'm using the following workaround but it feels awkward:

```py
try:
    raise ValueError('test')
except ValueError as err:
    def _tmp():
        breakpoint()
    _tmp()
    # (lambda: breakpoint())()  # or this one alternatively
```

Interestingly, using this version, I can also access the bound exception `err` when moving one frame up in the debugger:

```
$ python test.py 
--Return--
> test.py(5)_tmp()->None
-> breakpoint()
(Pdb) up
> test.py(6)<module>()
-> _tmp()
(Pdb) p err
ValueError('test')
```

## Disassembly via `dis`

In the following I compared two versions, one using `breakpoint` directly and the other wrapping it in a custom function `_breakpoint`:

```py
def _breakpoint():
    breakpoint()

try:
    raise ValueError('test')
except ValueError as err:
    breakpoint()   # version (a), cannot refer to 'err'
    # _breakpoint()  # version (b), can refer to 'err'
```

The output of `dis` is similar except for some memory locations and the name of the function of course:

[image: diff]

So it must be the additional stack frame that allows `pdb` to refer to the bound exception instance. However it is not clear why this is the case, since within the `except` block anything can refer to the bound exception instance.

Comment: Brilliant question :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the name of the application you are using to find the diff between the texts?

Comment: @JRodDynamite It's called [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`breakpoint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#breakpoint) is not a breakpoint in the sense that it halts execution at the exact location of this function call. Instead it's a shorthand for [`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.set_trace) which will halt execution at the *next* line of code (it calls [`sys.settrace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) under the covers). Since there is no more code inside the `except` block, execution will halt *after* that block has been exited and hence the name `err` is already deleted. This can be seen more clearly by putting an additional line of code after the `except` block:

```py
try:
    raise ValueError('test')
except ValueError as err:
    breakpoint()
print()
```

which gives the following:

```
$ python test.py 
> test.py(5)<module>()
-> print()
```

This means the interpreter is about to execute the `print()` statement in line 5 and it has already executed everything prior to it (including deletion of the name `err`).

When using another function to wrap the `breakpoint()` then the interpreter will halt execution at the `return` event of that function and hence the `except` block is not yet exited (and `err` is still available):

```
$ python test.py 
--Return--
> test.py(5)<lambda>()->None
-> (lambda: breakpoint())()
```

Exiting of the `except` block can also be delayed by putting an additional `pass` statement after the `breakpoint()`:

```py
try:
    raise ValueError('test')
except ValueError as err:
    breakpoint()
    pass
```

which results in:

```
$ python test.py 
> test.py(5)<module>()
-> pass
(Pdb) p err
ValueError('test')
```

Note that the `pass` has to be put on a separate line, otherwise it will be skipped:

```
$ python test.py 
--Return--
> test.py(4)<module>()->None
-> breakpoint(); pass
(Pdb) p err
*** NameError: name 'err' is not defined
```

Note the `--Return--` which means the interpreter has already reached the end of the module.

Comment: This is the answer. Interesting. An analogy would be how you'd insert a breakpoint on a line in an IDE. That mental model makes a lot of sense. Thanks @a_guest :) You learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent question!

When something strange is going on, I always dis-assemble the Python code and have a look a the byte code.

This can be done with the `dis` module from the standard library.

Here, there is the problem, that I cannot dis-assemble the code when there is a breakpoint in it :-)

So, I modified the code a bit, and set a marker variable `abc = 10` to make visible what happens after the `except` statement.

Here is my modified code, which I saved as `main.py`.

```
try:
    raise ValueError('test')
except ValueError as err:
    abc = 10
```

When you then dis-assemble the code...

```
❯ python -m dis main.py 
  1           0 SETUP_FINALLY           12 (to 14)

  2           2 LOAD_NAME                0 (ValueError)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 ('test')
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 RAISE_VARARGS            1
             10 POP_BLOCK
             12 JUMP_FORWARD            38 (to 52)

  3     >>   14 DUP_TOP
             16 LOAD_NAME                0 (ValueError)
             18 COMPARE_OP              10 (exception match)
             20 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       50
             22 POP_TOP
             24 STORE_NAME               1 (err)
             26 POP_TOP
             28 SETUP_FINALLY            8 (to 38)

  4          30 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
             32 STORE_NAME               2 (abc)
             34 POP_BLOCK
             36 BEGIN_FINALLY
        >>   38 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             40 STORE_NAME               1 (err)
             42 DELETE_NAME              1 (err)
             44 END_FINALLY
             46 POP_EXCEPT
             48 JUMP_FORWARD             2 (to 52)
        >>   50 END_FINALLY
        >>   52 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             54 RETURN_VALUE
```

You get a feeling what is going on.

You can read more about the `dis` module both in the excellent documentation or on the **Python module of the week** site:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html
https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html

Certainly, this is not a perfect answer. Actually, I have to sit down and read documentation myself. I am surprised that `SETUP_FINALLY` was called before the variable `abc` in the `except` block was handled. Also, I am not sure what's the effect of `POP_TOP` - immediately executed after storing the `err` name.

P.S.: Excellent question! I am super excited how this turns out.

Comment: Why can't you disassemble the code when it contains a `breakpoint()`? It's just another function call (it works for me). It's interesting to see the bytecode but I'm not sure if it helps in answering the question. I compared `dis` versions containing `breakpoint()` and `(lambda: breakpoint())()` and they are similar except for the part where the function is called (e.g. the `DELETE_NAME` happens at the same time). So the relevant difference (and for `pdb` only, since inside an `except` block you obviously can access the bound exception), seems to be the additional stack frame from the lambda.

Comment: To me, this does not contain an answer to the question. Hence -1

Answer (score -1):

### How can I access the exception instance?

Well, this is the easy part. When using `breakpoint()`, I always just make a copy of the `err` variable;

```py
try:
    raise ValueError('foo')
except Exception as err:
    e = err
    breakpoint()
```

which produces

```py
PS C:\tmp> python .\test_exc.py
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: e
Out[1]: ValueError('foo')
```

*(I am using `IPython.embed()` instead of the `pdb.set_trace()` as my `PYTHONBREAKPOINT`)*

### Why is this the case?

Maybe a look into the [try statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) helps. It says:

> When an exception has been assigned using as target, it is cleared at
> the end of the except clause. This is as if
>
> ```
> except E as N:
>     foo
> ```
>
> was translated to
>
> ```
> except E as N:
>     try:
>         foo
>     finally:
>         del N
> ```
>
> This means the exception must be assigned to a different name to be
> able to refer to it after the except clause. Exceptions are cleared
> because with the traceback attached to them, they form a reference
> cycle with the stack frame, keeping all locals in that frame alive
> until the next garbage collection occurs.

Now, apparently, if the `pdb.set_trace()` (or `IPython.embed()`) is at the last line of the except block, it will exit the exception block and executes the implicit `finally` suite.